# Histograms or Density plots of time of day

Tags: r, datetime

I have the data.frame in which every row is an episode with a start and an end timestamp.

```
test.DF<-dput(head(test.DF, n=50))
structure(list(start = structure(c(1189494920, 1189495400, 1189496120, 
1189496840, 1189497440, 1189498040, 1189498640, 1189501760, 1189503560, 
1190453600, 1247458520, 1247480840, 1247482880, 1247483840, 1247485040, 
1247486600, 1247487320, 1247488040, 1247488760, 1247490920, 1247491280, 
1247492480, 1247493680, 1247502440, 1247503160, 1247503520, 1247548040, 
1247549360, 1247550680, 1247552600, 1247553920, 1247557400, 1247558000, 
1247558480, 1247559440, 1247560400, 1247563760, 1247564960, 1247566640, 
1247567120, 1194935549, 1194936029, 1195722629, 1195724309, 1199691029, 
1199692349, 1202560229, 1208063669, 1208322989, 1188188112), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), end = structure(c(1189495280, 1189495520, 
1189496360, 1189497080, 1189497560, 1189498160, 1189498760, 1189501880, 
1189503920, 1190453720, 1247458640, 1247480960, 1247483480, 1247484080, 
1247485640, 1247486840, 1247487560, 1247488640, 1247490440, 1247491160, 
1247491520, 1247492600, 1247493920, 1247502680, 1247503400, 1247504120, 
1247549240, 1247550560, 1247551280, 1247552720, 1247554400, 1247557880, 
1247558240, 1247559080, 1247559560, 1247560760, 1247563880, 1247565080, 
1247566760, 1247567240, 1194935669, 1194936269, 1195722749, 1195724429, 
1199691269, 1199692469, 1202560349, 1208063789, 1208323109, 1188204792
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("start", 
"end"), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to see the distribution of these episodes within a 24 hour cycle. That is either a histogram or a density plot, with the 24H day cycle in the x axis. Is this possible? I would like to ignore the dates of the episodes.

Comment: `library(fortunes); fortune(109)`

Comment: it doesn't look like anything in your data indicates an episode.  Is this all one episode, many episodes?   How would you like your plot to look like?   Details would be helpful

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried. Cheers.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta : The data are start and stop timestapms of episodes. I am (was) looking for a graph like Mark in the box answered.

Comment: @Henrik : I fail to see the relevance or aim of your comment.

Comment: The aim of my comment was to remind you of one of the [stackoverflow guidelines (pt 3)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking for code must [i]nclude attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results".

Comment: @ECII, it seems like you are asking for free consultancy work.  I am pretty sure you should have an outstanding invoice with Marc.  At the very least you owe him a beer

Comment: Guys, lower your guns give peace a chance. I am totally unfamiliar with handling dates in R, I had tried some (admittedly awkward) stuff but didn't get me anywhere near a solution that's why I posted a plain question. I will be more than willing to buy anyone that contributed to my question a beer. And for Marc two. Also, if anyone can point me to info on handling dates in R, I would be very thankful. Cheers to all, thank you all for your contributions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By converting to a `POSIXlt`format, you can easily extract the hour of the time:

```
par(mar=c(6,4,1,1))
Hour <- as.POSIXlt(test.DF$start)$hour
hist(Hour, breaks=seq(0, 23), main="Start time (hour)")
```

[image]

#### Edit: Adding a value for ever minute between start and end

```
fun <- function(start.time, end.time){
    seq.POSIXt(
        as.POSIXlt(
            paste0("2000-01-01 ", as.POSIXlt(start.time)$hour, ":", as.POSIXlt(start.time)$min)
        ),
        as.POSIXlt(
            paste0("2000-01-01 ", as.POSIXlt(end.time)$hour, ":", as.POSIXlt(end.time)$min)
        ),
        by="min"
    )
}


HM <- vector(mode="list", dim(test.DF)[1])
for(i in seq(HM)){
    HM[[i]] <- fun(test.DF$start[i], test.DF$end[i])
}

HM2 <- as.POSIXlt(unlist(HM), origin="1970-01-01")

Hour <- HM2$hour 
hist(Hour, breaks=seq(0, 23))

HourMinute <- HM2$hour + HM2$min/60
hist(HourMinute, breaks=seq(0, 23, by=1/60))
```

[image]

Comment: Marc thanks a lot. However this is the distribution of the starting times. I would like the distribution of the whole episode duration. That is if an episode lasts one hour (lets say between 9 and 10 am), every minute between 9 and 10 should be added to the histogram.

Comment: @ECII - You're asking a lot here - This was definitely not clear in your question. Henrick's comments to provide a bit more effort of what you have done might would be helpful next time.

Comment: You and Henrik are probably right. Will do next time. Thanks a lot.