# Split time from timedate and make a histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TauIf.png)The data is in a .csv file in the format below:
"04/06/2019  15:01:00"

Already tried:

```
test <- read.csv("file") #base file
time <- strptime(test$dReceievedDate) #strips out date/time
time2 <- time[,2] #this seems to just show the time
```

But any plots I attempt do not work

```
ggplot(data=test) + aes(x=time2) + geom_histogram(bins = 24)
```

> Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?

https://file.io/b5cXCE

Comment: I have attached an image now to help

Comment: Input data is .csv file in format shown in pic.  Output is just a histogram showing count of orders on y axis and by time bins(in hours) on x axis.  Seems v difficult to do for some reason!

Comment: Pictures of data aren't helpful because we can't copy/paste the data. Also, all the other columns seem to be irrelevant to your question. The link I provided shows way to share data such that we can copy/paste it into R for testing.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559355/histograms-or-density-plots-of-time-of-day

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303351/histogram-over-time-of-day

Comment: I have tried these suggestions and they don't work for me.  I will attach the data now.  Thanks